# A surface is essential iff each component of it is essential?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

First, for the terms, A surface is essential if it is both incompressible and boundary-incompressible.

I want to show that A surface S is essential if ans only if each components of S is essential.

My idea, for the *only if* part, is to suppose a component of S, `S_i`, is not essential. So it either has  compressing disk, or not boundary-incompressible. In either case, the disk D is a compressing disk for S, or it bounds a disk on the boundary of S. But it is a contradiction, since S is essential.

Is it correct?

And, for the *if* part, I have no idea.
Can any one help me with this?